# Why i have to create instance if hashset manually in many to many relationship?cant spring do it for me?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, relationship

hello everyone can someone explain why do i have to create an instance of HashSet ? and is there a way to avoid it ?

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
      private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: You can make just a `List` instead of `Set`. `private List<Movie> movies;`

Comment: What do you mean you *have to* create a `HashSet`? Have you tried not initializing the field? What happened when you did?